# regex to validate string from a variable value

Tags: linux, sed

```
var1="temp-pprod-deployment"
```

Need a shell script for the below use case;

if the above variable $var1 value contains "prod" string then execute a print message eg. echo "Found" else echo "Not found"

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this? wouldn't a simple shell glob suffice e.g. (in a Bourne-like shell) `case $var1 in *prod*) echo 'Found';; *) echo 'Not found';; esac`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var1="temp-pprod-deployment"
if `echo "$var1" | grep -q "prod"` ;then
   echo "\$var1 contains word 'prod'"
else 
   echo "Not found."
fi
```

Explanation: You are getting output of variable and piping it to grep for regex. The `-q` option, means to return 0 on success(true) and 1 on failure(false), which is `test`-ed with `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Use bashes / operator to remove the test string from the variable contents, and see if that operation has changed it.  If it has, you know the string is present:

```
$ var1="temp-pprod-deployment"
$ var2="temp-pdev-deployment"
$ [ "${var1/prod}" == "$var1" ] && echo not found
$ [ "${var2/prod}" == "$var2" ] && echo not found
not found
$ [ "${var1/dev}" == "$var1" ] && echo not found
not found
$ [ "${var2/dev}" == "$var2" ] && echo not found
```

In full compliance with the OP:

```
if [ "${var1/prod}" != "${var1}" ]
then
  echo "Found."
else
  echo "Not found."
fi
```